# Subtract quantity from database inventory based on drop down lists ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am trying to build an ASP.NET page that will allow someone to select a jar, scent, and color from drop down lists on a page. The drop down lists are populated from the database tables for this example:

Jars.dbo Jar Quantity
  - Status Jar  20 OH   (holds .5 oz fragrance and .5 dye chip)

Scents.dbo
Scent 
Quantity   - Beachwood 100 oz OH

and

Dyes.dbo
Color
Quantity  - Red 20 chips OH

Now I want the user to be able to select the values from the drop down lists to make their specific custom candle order. Based on their selection of the jar the quantity of scent or dye will vary. However I want to subtract that amount from the database so as the keep inventory up to date. I am trying to figure out how to link the databases together.  I was thinking to use an order id that would be generated at a complete order however this wont work because I cannot populate the database while leaving the primary key null. So this question has a few parts, any and all help is much appreciated y'all.

1) How to get database to subtract quantity of scent or dye based on the jar?

2) How to link database tables which are the materials that go into the candle (i.e. scent, dye, jar, wick), what would be a primary key that would work I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have these tables in different databases?  Anyway, you have the right idea.  When your order is submitted (you have your order id), just decrement the quantity in your quantity tables by the amount ordered.

Something like this - probably a good idea to put this in a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO Orders(JarId, ScentId, ColorId, JarQty, ScentQty, ColorQty....)
VALUES(@jarIdOrdered, @scentIdOrdered, @colorIdOrdered, @jarQty, @scentQty, @colorQty...)

UPDATE Jar SET Quantity = Quantity - @jarQty
WHERE JarId = @jarIdOrdered

UPDATE Scent SET Quantity = Quantity - @scentQty
WHERE ScentId = @scentIdOrdered

UPDATE Color SET Quantity = Quantity - @colorQty
WHERE ColorId = @colorIdOrdered
```